# Как автоматически настраивать высоту child элемента в ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Есть `ExpandableListView`, который содержит группы и вложенные элементы групп. В каждом элементе группы содержится 2 текстовых поля (слева и справа). Бывает такое, что текст в текстовом поле вложенного элемента группы слишком большой, и он разбивается на 3 строки. После этого он не помещается в высоту элемента группы.

Как сделать так, чтобы высота элемента группы устанавливалась автоматически в зависимости от количества текста в первом текстовом поле?
Разметка для child элемента

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewChild"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"

        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewChild1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"

        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/backgroun_button_nazad"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:gravity="center" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо для текстового поля указать высоту равную `wrap_content` и для его контейнера-родителя указать высоту равную `match_parent`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewChild"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewChild1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"    
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/backgroun_button_nazad"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Стоит везде wrap_content

Comment: @ЕленаЧччччччч, хм... А ширина тоже?.. Если да, то попробуйте её через вес или `dp` задать. Если не поможет - добавьте разметку в вопрос.

Comment: разметку добавила. Насчет веса не поняла идею. dp не хотелось бы использовать, т.к. придется прописывать для разных экранов свое.

Comment: @ЕленаЧччччччч, см. обновлённый ответ.

Comment: а вот так нормально, правда еще поколдовала с пэдингами, чтобы оставить гравити

Comment: @ЕленаЧччччччч, значит текстовым полям надо было `wrap_content`, а контейнеру `match_parent`, а веса и отступы уж тут ничего не испортят)